# Calculate a value based on previous value (loop)

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, date, sql-server-2012

Can someone please help me understand what type of function to use or direction to go in order to solve the problem below? I have done most of the work on the script but I am stuck at trying to figure out how to define a date one at a time from top to bottom. For example, Calculate first date on row one then calculate second date one row 2 based on first date on row one.

Example table I created:

```
Employee  | WorkDate  | #ofBreaksInWks  |  EndDate   |  StartDate
123         1/4/2016                                    1/4/2016
123         1/5/2016            
123         1/6/2016      2 
123         1/27/2016   
123         1/28/2016     5               *1/28/2016   *3/10/2016
123         3/10/2016   
123         3/9/2016      1 
123         3/25/2016       
123         4/1/2016            
123         4/10/2016           
123         4/15/2016     4
```

=`Today's date *05/15/2016`

=`Values with asterisk* will be calculative`

If I worked 4 or <13 weeks then I need to assign an end date to an employee depending on how much I worked.

1. I have defined very first start date which is `MIN` of all worked dates `"1/4/2016"`
2. I look for the first break that is greater than 3. I see that there is a 5 weeks break. I have to check if I have worked more than I took off. `WorkDate` minus `StartDate` (`1/28/2016` -`3/10/2016`). If it is greater than 5 weeks then I assign an end date which is a `WorkDate`.
3. Then I go for next one. I see 4 weeks (`4/15/2016` - `*05/15/2016`) , so I do the calculation to see if an employee has worked more than 4 weeks. In this case employee has worked 5 weeks. Calculated by previous `StartDate` `3/10/2016` minus `4/15/2016` (`WorkDate`).

I know how to calculate Start and End date but I am not sure how accomplish this one at a time, because every next row is depended on the previous value. Please help!

Comment: What is the datatype of your date fields?

Comment: @Shell Datetime

Comment: I don't know if a database is the best solution for this problem.  SQL Server is not designed for time-series analysis.  Ideally, every row should be one unit of data, completely independent from the other units in that table.  Perhaps Excel is a better tool, or something designed to handle these series dependencies.

Comment: Instead of looping you should look into LEAD/LAG. This also has the sound of being an islands and gaps situation (You should google that and you will find some excellent examples). Either way, looping for this is NOT the way to go.

Comment: So a "break" is something like a full Sunday-to-Saturday week with no work days recorded??

Comment: @shawnt00 yes full week with no work date recorded

Comment: Why does 3/9 get the notation instead of 3/10?

Comment: @shawnt00 Employee worked 3/10 then took off a week and came back 3rd week which is 3/25. So they have one week break in the middle. If it make sense, its # of weeks break "AFTER".

Comment: @SeanLange been researching about Lead/LAG. It seems it get the previous/next value. Not sure if it can be used to calculate

Comment: You'll have better luck if you can explain my previous question and also what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you indeed use SQL Server 2008, then it doesn't have `LEAD` / `LAG` functions. They were added in 2012.

Comment: @shawnt00 original data is everything in the table except values w/ asterisk. I need to define an `EndDate` and the way i can do it is to look for any1 with 4 or <13 weeks break. Break is calculated by subtracting `WorkDate`s in weeks. To calculate an `EndDate` I need to start from top because every `EndDate` is defined by previous `StartDate` and we only have very first `StartDate` to work with. When an `EndDate` is defined, then we go next to see another break >3 and if there is any then we calculate the difference from the `WorkDate` to `StartDate` of LAST `EndDate`. I explained this above.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I have 2012. After researching, I can't really think of a way `LEAD`/`LAG` will be able to help solve my problem because I need to define one value at a time because next value will be based on previous calculative value. The only good solution I can see is `While Loop`.

Comment: @user3483150 You did indeed attempt to explain that in the question and it didn't make any more sense than your second attempt in the comment. It's unfair to expect us to decipher the objective of this whole exercise. You failed to address my question about 3/9 and 3/10. You can't describe why it matters that breaks must be greater than 3 and why you intend to search them in order of decreasing length. I could go on and on with questions but I'd clearly be wasting my time.

Comment: @user3483150 I was literally about to sit down and try to work up an attempted solution for you. But after that "I explained this above" comment  you're on your own.

Comment: @shawnt00 Please do me a favor and don't help. I was never looking for a complete solution but just a direction. I did answer your question as soon as you asked. Maybe if you would've asked the way you did now "in detail", I would've better understood your question. Don't need to get all mean about this. You WEREN'T clear with your question to begin with. I still appreciate your attempt to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by using a Temp Table and a While loop that has a Processed flag.

```
            IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTempTable') IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE #YourTempTable;
            END

            -- Populate Temp Table
            SELECT
                Processed = 0,
                Id,
                Employee,
                WorkDate,
                EndDate,
                StartDate
            INTO
                #YourTempTable
            FROM
                DataSourceTable;

                DECLARE @Id int = 0;
                DECLARE @LastId int = 0;
                DECLARE @Employee nvarchar(30) = '';
                DECLARE @WorkDate int = 0;
                DECLARE @LastWorkDate int = 0;

                WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Processed FROM #YourTempTable WHERE Processed = 0)
                BEGIN
                    SELECT TOP 1
                        @Id = Id,
                        @Employee = Employee,
                        @WorkDate = WorkDate
                    FROM
                        #YourTempTable
                    WHERE
                        Processed = 0;

                    UPDATE
                        DataSourceTable
                    SET
                        NewDefinedDate = @WorkDate -- Combined with something with @LastWorkDate
                    WHERE 
                        Id = @Id;

                    SET @LastId = @Id;
                    SET @LastWorkDate = @LastWorkDate;

                    UPDATE
                        #YourTempTable
                    SET
                        Processed = 1
                    WHERE
                        Id = @Id;
                END
            END

            IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTempTable') IS NOT NULL)
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE #YourTempTable;
            END
```

Comment: this is a great idea. i am going to do some research about while loop and will try your suggestion. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Looping here is not a great approach from a performance perspective. You also are using top 1 but that query does not have an order by which means you don't know which row you will get back.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with weeks as (    
     select
         Employee,
         datediff(week, '20000102', WorkDate) as weekNum,
         min(WorkDate) as workDate,
         row_number() over (
             partition by Employee
             order by datediff(week, '20000102', WorkDate)
         ) as rowNum
     from emp
     group by Employee, datediff(week, '20000102', WorkDate)
), islands as (
    select
        Employee,
        min(workDate) as workDate,
        datediff(week, min(workDate), max(workDate)) + 1 as workWeeks
    from weeks
    group by Employee, weekNum - rowNum
), gaps as (
    select *,
        datediff(week,
            workDate,
            lead(workDate) over (partition by Employee order by workDate)
        ) - workWeeks as breakWeeks
    from islands
)
select * from gaps
-- where breakWeeks > workWeeks; ??
```

I still don't understand the full nature of this question but here's a working version of the previous attempt I typed out on my phone a few days ago. It determines the number of weeks in a consecutive run of worked weeks and then computes the number of non-worked weeks between itself and the start of the next run. This is a non-looping approach to the problem. Hopefully it gets you closer to a solution.

http://rextester.com/LFAH31486